# Authentication of Rails user for Android app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a school project.  We are going to make a bug/rodent themed tower defense game.  The game will primarily be an Android app. There will also be (at least we want there to be) a Ruby on Rails website/application tied together with it.

One of the requirements for the project is to implement three levels of user that will interact with the project.  We decided that the three types of users will be administrators, guest players, and players with accounts.  Players with accounts will be able to accumulate perks.  Guest players will be able to play, but won't have any capacity to earn perks over time.  The administrators will be able to manage the users with accounts (delete, edit, et cetera) via a web browser and the Rails application.

I want the users with accounts to be able to login to the Rails application via the Android app.  There will be parts of the game that only users with accounts will be able to access. How can we create a login/logout scheme for the Android app?  I'm thinking it will be something like the user enters their username/password, taps login, and then the Android app will send a request to the Rails side.  Once the user is logged in via the Android app, they can access certain parts of the Android app that guest users cannot.

How would I go about this?  I'm not sure where to start.

Would the Android app, using Java, send http requests to the Rails application (sending the username and password)?  Then would the Rails application send back some sort of success?  How would the Android app hold onto this successful login like a session in a web browser?  Also, the Android app will need to update user attributes in the Rails database (something like accumulated perks).

Is this possible?

I've seen miscellaneous information about how to do this scattered online in blogs, on stackoverflow, and on discussion boards.  But, I haven't found a coherent solution for my group's needs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your rails apps as an oauth provider (https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin) and use an oauth client library on the mobile application

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to where I should start learning how to accomplish this?  Appreciate the suggestion.